# Can't Resolve Nested Enums

Tags: c++

I'm looking to do something like the following:

```
class Whatever {
public:

    enum PhysicalObjectType {
            STATIC_MISC_OBJECT,
            DYNAMIC_MISC_OBJECT,
            STATIC_MISC_OBJECT_WALKABLE,
            DYNAMIC_MISC_OBJECT_WALKABLE,
            STATIC_MISC_OBJECT_KILL,
            DYNAMIC_MISC_OBJECT_KILL,
            STATIC_MISC_OBJECT_BREAK,
            DYNAMIC_MISC_OBJECT_BREAK,
            BOUNDARY,
            BOUNDARY_GROUND,
            PERMANENT_JOINT,
            MOUSE_JOINT
    };
};
```

And then a method that will retrieve a type based on the above code outside of the class. So lets say within another class I have an instance of `Whatever` and I call getType() on `myWhateverInstance` and do a comparison to determine what type it is, like so:

```
if( myWhateverInstance.getType() == STATIC_MISC_OBJECT ) {

}else ...
```

That however, is not working. Basically no matter how I try and resolve them, I cannot access any values within the enum outside of the class. What noob mistake am I making here? (Note the specific errors I'm getting are not declared in scope or XX is not a valid namespace or class, etc).

Comment: `Whatever::STATIC_MISC_OBJECT`. Corrected. Using enum name is non-standard MS extention.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When accessing enumerators that are members of a class, you have to qualify their names with the class's name. So the enumerators are `Whatever::STATIC_MISC_OBJECT` and so forth.

This is only necessary when accessing the enumerator from outside of the class. From within the class's scope, you can simply use the base name.

Comment: Thanks... duh, should have known. For some reasons when I first tried to access by qualifying with the class name, it gave me a compiler error which threw me off. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

The enum is a member of the class, you need to qualify it with the class name (unless the code is part of a method of that same class):

```
if( myWhateverInstance.getType() == Whatever::STATIC_MISC_OBJECT ) {
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class C
{
 public:
  enum E
  {
   EA, EB
  };
};

C::E en = C::EA;
```